# Is there a elementary HIG compliant video editor?

Tags: design, software-recommendation, video-editor

I know this is a long shot, but I was wondering, seeing as there are so many relative unknowns out there.

Comment: I am concerned we can never really answer "no" to this, other than to state that none of the existing options conform. It would be very interesting to see something as complex as a video editor try to follow the (fairly restrictive) guidelines. I may review this in depth tomorrow.

Comment: I guess I could rephrase this to ask if there are any elementary-focused video editor projects.

Comment: The same applies, I can only say there are none officially, not that no-one is making one.

Answer (score 4):

At this time you can be happy when having a *working* video editor on elementary OS.

Kdenlive from the 14.04 Repo is very outdated and has some problems. The newer builds from the ppa rely on newer dependencies and don't work on 14.04. It is also not very intuitive.

- https://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu
- https://launchpad.net/~sunab/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-release

Pitivi has still no stable build of the newer versions. But the UI looks really good. Maybe it is elementary HIG compliant?

- http://fundraiser.pitivi.org/download-bundles

You can install Openshot from the Ubuntu Repo. I haven't tested it but it seems to work.

Their PPA is outdated. They are working on the 2.0 release.

- http://www.openshot.org/ppa/

Cinelerra is really ugly and not intuitive at all! Maybe it works for some people. The version you can download from the website runs on freya.

- http://cinelerra.org/2015/

Comment: I wasn't asking for *any* video editor, so this answer is a bit off topic.